# Initializing array of integers without using square [] brackets

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, syntax

I was trying to initialize an array of int in c without the use of [] brackets. As far as I know, int A[n] is equivalent to int *(a+n). I tried initializing the array like this. However, it is not working.

When is this notation, i.e int *(a+n) used, and how can we initialize, scanf and print without using the square brackets?

Comment: `*(a+n)` is the same as `a[n]` everywhere except in a declaration. `int *(a+n)` is **not** a valid declaration. You could do `int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(int))`, but remember to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

Comment: Avoiding the use of [] brackets when writing C code is like avoiding the use of a hammer when building a house. You can certainly do it, but why bother.

Comment: @user3386109 It was a constraint in a ques I was trying..thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you don't want brackets, you don't want to use an array. You're looking for pointers here. The simplest way to allocate the required bytes of memory is to use `malloc()`, and then you can use `*(p + i)` like syntax to get data from the user or display the output.

Here's a [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HyQMEPKk_):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5  // Max number of elements (in words of an array)

int main(void) {
    // Declaration and initialization of the required pointer
    int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * MAX);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Enter %dth position value: ", i);

        // Verification of user input
        if (scanf("%d", (p + i)) != 1) { // equivalent to &*(p + i)
            puts("Incorrect value. Quitting...");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("%d\n", *(p + i)); // dereference to (p + i) used here

    free(p); // Free the memory before exit, unnecessary here
             // but good practice

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the sample code will be similar (notice the input as well):

```
Enter 0th position value: 5
Enter 1th position value: 3    // (correct to 1st)
Enter 2th position value: 8    // (correct to 2nd)
Enter 3th position value: 6    // (correct to 3rd)
Enter 4th position value: 3
5
3
8
6
3
```

---

<sup>**Note:** This doesn't mean the arrays are bad.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `{` and `}` with [Digraphs (C11 6 4 6)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.6) or [Trigraph sequences (C11 5.2.1.1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1.1).

The three statements below are equivalent:

```
foo[bar] = baz[quux] + zxc[spqr];
foo<:bar:> = baz<:quux:> + zxc<:spqr:>;
foo??(bar??) = baz??(quux??) + zxc??(spqr??);
```

<sub>*thanks to [The Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/index.html) for the [metasyntactic variables](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html).*</sub>